# How to mock Mapstruct's toDto method using Mockito for page.map(mapper::toDto)

Tags: java, junit, java-8, mockito, mapstruct

I am writing a `junit` test case for my `service` method which has an external call to `jpa repository`, which I would like to `mock`.
This method `findall(Pageable pageable)` returns a `page` of entities which is being mapped by `Mapstruct's` mapper. 
However, I get an `NPE` when I `assert` the return. 
There might be something which I am missing, I am not sure how to `mock` this method call.

I tried writing **test case** like this
Test case:

```
public class myTestclass {
@Test
public void testFindAllUser() {
User user1 = new User();
user1.setId(Long.valueOf(1));
User user2 = new User();
user2.setId(Long.valueOf(2));
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
userList.add(user1);
userList.add(asset2);

Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 5);
Page<User> userPage = new PageImpl<>(userList, pageable, userList.size());
Page<UserDto> userDtoPage = null;
Mockito.when(userRepositoryMock.findAll(pageable)).thenReturn(userPage);
Mockito.when(userPage.map(userMapperMock::toDto)).thenReturn(userDtoPage);// expecting to mock this object in
// some other way.
assertThat(userService.findAll(pageable)).isEqualTo(userDtoPage); // throws NPE
}
}
```

The method for which i am writing the test case:

```
public Page<UserDto> findAll(Pageable pageable) 
{

return userRepository.findAll(pageable).map(userMapper::toDto);
}
```

This is my mapper class:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { FarmerMapper.class })

public interface UserMapper extends EntityMapper<UserDto, User> {

UserDto toDto(User user);

User toEntity(UserDto userDto);
}
```

What is the right way to mock the `mapper` method `toDto` so that it returns a page of `userDto`?

Comment: I think the problem is not the mocking of the `toDto` method. This part seems correct to me. I think the problem might be that you define a mock on `userRepositoryMock` for the method `findAll` but then call the method `findAll` on a different object `userService` which seems to be not even definded in this scope. Also the mocked method `userPage.map(...)` is never called. Can you explain more specific what the problem is and what you need?

Comment: For the sake of simplicity I did not mention the declaration part of `userMapper` . 
It is autowired into `userService` class. 

The mock statements in the test case give a better idea as to what I am trying to achieve. 
`Mockito.when(userRepositoryMock.findAll(pageable)).thenReturn(userPage);` mocks the `userRepositoryMock`'s findAll which is working fine. it returns `Page<User>`
`Mockito.when(userPage.map(userMapperMock::toDto)).thenReturn(userDtoPage);` should ideally mock the `toDto` method but it does not seem to work.

Comment: As far as I understand you are mocking the wrong method. When calling `when(userPage.map(userMapperMock::toDto)).thenReturn(...);` you're mocking the method `map`instead of `toDto`. Another idea would be to use any `Function` as parameter like this: `when(userPage.map(Matchers.<Function<?, ?>>any())).thenReturn(...);`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I tried to mock `map` function instead of `toDto` method.
I tried mocking each object returned by the toDto methood and it worked as expected.
`Mockito.when(userMapperMock.toDto(user1)).thenReturn(userDto1);` 
If there are multiple objects in the page I am mocking each one of them. 
I am hoping there is a better way to do this, but for now this works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `.map` uses `UserMapper's toDto` Method to convert each element of the page, I mocked multiple elements of `userMapper` to resolve this problem.

Hence I created 2 pages, one for `User` and another for `UserDto`. 
So my test case was modified as

```
@Test
public void testFindAllUser() {
User user1 = new User();
user1.setId(DEFAULT_ID);
User user2 = new User();
user2.setId(2L);
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
userList.add(user1);
userList.add(user2);
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 5);
Page<User> userPage = new PageImpl<>(userList, pageable, userList.size());

UserDto userDto1 = new UserDto();
userDto1.setId(Long.valueOf(1));
UserDto userDto2 = new UserDto();
userDto2.setId(Long.valueOf(2));
List<UserDto> userDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
userDtoList.add(userDto1);
userDtoList.add(userDto2);
Page<UserDto> userDtoPage = new PageImpl<>(userDtoList, pageable, userDtoList.size());

Mockito.when(userMapperMock.toDto(user1)).thenReturn(userDto1);
Mockito.when(userMapperMock.toDto(user2)).thenReturn(userDto2); //Mocking the toDto method. 

Mockito.when(userRepositoryMock.findAll(pageable)).thenReturn(userPage);
assertThat(userService.findAll(pageable)).isEqualTo(userDtoPage);
}
```

Now, if there are more number of elements to be added to the Page, I would mock the same `toDto` for all of the elements.